# MPEG 2 and 2.5 - problems calculating frame sizes in bytes

Tags: mp3, frame, mpeg

I have a console program which I have used for years, for (among other things) displaying info about certain audio-file formats, including mp3. I used data from the mpeghdr site to calculate the frame sizes, in order to further calculate playing time for the tracks. The equation that I got from mpeghdr was:

```
// Read the BitRate, SampleRate and Padding of the frame header. 
// For Layer I files use this formula: 
// 
//     FrameLengthInBytes = (12 * BitRate / SampleRate + Padding) * 4 
// 
// For Layer II & III files use this formula: 
// 
//     FrameLengthInBytes = 144 * BitRate / SampleRate + Padding
```

This works well for most mp3 files, but there have always been a small subset for whom this equation failed. Recently, I've been looking at a set of very small mp3 files, and have found that for these files this formula fails *much* more often, so I'm trying to finally nail down what is going on.  All of these mp3 files were generated using Lame V3.100, with default settings, on Windows 7 64-bit.

In all cases, I can successfully find the first frame header, but when I used the above formula to calculate the offset to the *next* frame header, it is sometimes not correct.

As an example, I have a file 'wolf howl.mp3'; analytical files such as [MPEGAudioInfo](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8295/MPEG-Audio-Frame-Header) show frame size as 288 bytes. When I run my program, though, it shows length of first frame as 576 bytes (2 * 288). When I look at the mp3 file in a hex editor, with first frame at 0x154, I can see that the next frame is at 0x154 + 208 bytes, but this calculation *does* in fact result in 576 bytes...

```
File info:
mpegV2.5, layer III

frame: bitrate=32, sample_rate=8000, pad=0, bytes=576
mtemp->frame_length_in_bytes =
   (144 * (mtemp->bitrate * 1000) / mtemp->sample_rate) + mtemp->padding_bit;
which equals 576
```

I've looked at numerous other references, and they all show this equation...
At first I thought is was an issue with MPEG 2.5, which is an unofficial standard, but I have also seen this with MPEG2 files as well.  Only happens with small files, though.

Does anyone have any insights on what I am missing here??

//**************************************

Later notes:

I thought maybe audio format would be relevant to this issue, so I dumped channel_mode and mode_extension for each of my test files (3 calculate properly, 2 don't). Sadly, all of them are cmode=3, mode_ext=0
(i.e., last byte of the header is 0xC4)... so that doesn't help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Some documents, I've read, don't define dividing by 2 in Frame-Size formula for MPEG2.5L3. But some src-code, I encountered - does.
It's hard to find out any proof.
I have nothing better than this link:
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4615-0327-9_12

(it's better to share that link in "add a comment"-form, but I have insufficient rank)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found the answer to this queston... it was in the MPEGAudioInfo program on CodeProject site.  Here is the vital key:

```
//*************************************************************************************
//  This reference data is from MPEGAudioInfo app
// Samples per Frame / 8
static const u32 m_dwCoefficients[2][3] =
{
   {  // MPEG 1
      12,   // Layer1   (must be multiplied with 4, because of slot size)
      144,  // Layer2
      144   // Layer3
   },
   {  // MPEG 2, 2.5
      12,   // Layer1   (must be multiplied with 4, because of slot size)
      144,  // Layer2
      72    // Layer3
   }  
};
```

It is unfortunately that none of the reference pages mention this detail !!
My program now successfully calculates frame sizes for *all* of my mp3 files, including the small ones.